# Find the limit as $x$ tends towards $\frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: calculus, limits

In looking at the corresponding graph and differentiating it after reducing it to a different form, I know the that limit is equal to $2$ but I am unsure as to how I can show this algebraically. Any hints would be appreciated.

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \pi/4} \frac{1-\tan x }{1-\sqrt2 \, \sin x}$$

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: $x$ or $\theta$?

Comment: Are you sure that the limit is equal to $2$ ?

Comment: its limit is pi/4

Comment: Mathematica says the limit equals $2(2+\sqrt{2})$. I think you've made a mistake in typing the question.

Comment: are you sure? I can see pi/4

Comment: @user3397 Oh I didn't see the latest edit.

Comment: @user3397 Even then the limit is not 2 it's 0.

Comment: Please fix if it is $-\pi/4$ or $\pi/4$

Comment: im sorry its sin theta not sin^2 theta, ill edit it!

Comment: The limit to 2 i'm extremely sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to\dfrac\pi4}\frac{1-\tan x}{1-\sqrt2\sin x}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to\dfrac\pi4}\frac{\cos x-\sin x}{1-\sqrt2\sin x}\cdot\frac1{\lim_{x\to\dfrac\pi4}(\cos x)}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to\dfrac\pi4}\frac{(\cos x-\sin x)(\cos x+\sin x)}{(1-\sqrt2\sin x)(1+\sqrt2\sin x)}\cdot\lim_{x\to\dfrac\pi4}\frac{(1+\sqrt2\sin x)}{(\cos x+\sin x)}\cdot\frac1{\dfrac1{\sqrt2}}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to\dfrac\pi4}\frac{\cos2x}{\cos2x}\cdot\lim_{x\to\dfrac\pi4}\frac{(1+\sqrt2\sin x)}{(\cos x+\sin x)}\cdot\sqrt2$$

as $\displaystyle(\cos x-\sin x)(\cos x+\sin x)=\cos^2x-\sin^2x=\cos2x$

and  $\displaystyle(1-\sqrt2\sin x)(1+\sqrt2\sin x)=1-2\sin^2x=\cos2x$

and as $\displaystyle x\to\dfrac\pi4,x\ne\dfrac\pi4,\cos2x\ne0$

Comment: But when i substitute x=pi/4 into the equation i get 2^(1/2), where as the limit = 2

Comment: @user3397, have you followed the method? How do you assure the limit $=2$ to be correct ?

Comment: I looked at its graph and i differentiated it's reduced form.  
Heres the graph:  
goo.gl/Q7EzC1

Comment: @user3397, From the start, we have forgotten $\cos x$ which has been incorporated

Comment: @user3397, Can have a look into http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/865509/solving-a-trigonometric-limit/867089#867089

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to\dfrac\pi4}\frac{1-\tan x}{1-\sqrt2\sin x}$$

$$=\frac1{\sqrt2}\lim_{x\to\dfrac\pi4}\frac{\tan x-1}{\sin x-\dfrac1{\sqrt2}}$$

$$=\frac1{\sqrt2}\frac{\lim_{x\to\dfrac\pi4}\left(\dfrac{\tan x-\tan\dfrac\pi4}{x-\dfrac\pi4}\right)}{\lim_{x\to\dfrac\pi4}\left(\dfrac{\sin x-\sin\dfrac\pi4}{x-\dfrac\pi4}\right)}$$

$$=\frac1{\sqrt2}\cdot\frac{\dfrac{d(\tan x)}{dx}_{\left(\text{ at } x=\dfrac\pi4\right)}}{\dfrac{d(\sin x)}{dx}_{\left(\text{ at } x=\dfrac\pi4\right)}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Following orion's way, I will set $\displaystyle\frac\pi4-x=2y$

$$\lim_{x\to\dfrac\pi4}\frac{1-\tan x}{1-\sqrt2\sin x}$$

$$=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{1-\tan\left(\dfrac\pi4-2y\right)}{1-\sqrt2\sin\left(\dfrac\pi4-2y\right)}$$

$$=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{1-\dfrac{1-\tan2y}{1+\tan2y}}{1-(\cos2y-\sin2y)}$$

Using [double angle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html) formula this becomes,

$$2\frac1{\lim_{y\to0}(1+\tan2y)\cos2y}\cdot 2\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\sin2y}{2y}\frac1{\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{\sin y}y} \cdot\frac1{\lim_{y\to0}(\sin y+\cos y)}$$

Observe that all the limits reduce to $1$

Answer (score 1):

First, convert it to limit around zero with:
$$y=x-\frac{\pi}{4}$$
Expand all trigonometric functions with addition theorems. Things will become more obvious then. You can then use l'Hospital, further trigonometric manipulations to cancel things out, or just simple Taylor expansion.

EDIT:

$$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{1-\tan(y+\pi/4)}{1-\sqrt{2}\sin(y+\pi/4)}$$
$$=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{1-\frac{\tan y+\tan \pi/4}{1-\tan y \tan \pi/4}}{1-\sqrt{2}(\sin y\cos \frac{\pi}{4}+\cos y \sin{\frac{\pi}{4}})}$$
$$=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{1-\frac{1+\tan y}{1-\tan y}}{1-(\sin y+\cos y)}$$
$$=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{-2\tan y}{({1-\tan y})(1-(\sin y+\cos y))}$$
$$=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{-2\tan y}{1-\sin y -\cos y-\tan y+(\sin^2 y/\cos y)+\sin y}$$
Multiply by cosine on both sides
$$=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{-2\sin y}{1+\cos y -2\cos^2 y-\sin y}$$
You can solve this with l'Hospital now:
$$=\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{-2\cos y}{-\sin y -4\cos y\sin y-\cos y}=2$$

I oversimplified on purpose - you could do that a few lines earler. But it's nice to have it in this form in case you want to apply other methods (especially the Taylor approach).

Comment: I tried to convert the limit to lim h->0 so :(pi/4+h) and expanded it but i cant get to the form where i can subsitute h=0 and get the result=2 . I also want to prove it algebraically so i cant use l'hospital rule

Comment: I solved it using L'hospital rule too but i wanted to find a way to solve it using trig identities only without l'hospital

Comment: In that case, translate everything to the new variable of $t=\tan y/2$ and use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula to make this limit a rational function.

Comment: alright ill try that out too